# visual studio 2010 database project, is there a visual way?

Tags: database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, project

started a **visual studio 2010 database project**. however i am only able to write sql in a text mode, there is no functionality in making the table for example in a visual view as exists when you add a new database to app_data folder and the work on it there.

is this the only way and **there is no visual way of doing this in the visual studio 2010 database project?** or am i missing some obvious way of getting to it?

http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/9311/42342496.png

thank you

*also if there is a tutorial anywhere (video maybe!?) please link it. i only found importing a database from an existing script video using a wizard. would like new database from scratch without wizard.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a simple workaround you can use to have visual design capabilities. You need a dev database set up anywhere. Now create a schema synchronization with Visual Studios built-in Schema Comparison. This will allow you to pull changes between your dev database and your database project back and forth.

Since you can sync in both directions, you can make changes to your database via database diagrams from inside VS (via the Server Explorer) or you can use SQL Server Management Studio (or whatever else you like). When you're done, simply sync your changes using the schema comparison. It works in the opposite direction too, simply change one of your scripts and then sync with your dev database.

Comment: i shall try it. never used schema comparison. thnx for the tip :)

Comment: **thank you very much.** works like a charm. tried it both ways. awesome!

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and could not find the answer in the documentation or the net until i stumbled upon this question - thanks..

Comment: Just a note -- Schema Compare is only in the Premium and Ultimate editions of Visual Studio.